# Can we get contact store in phone memory only

Tags: android

Can we get contact store in phone memory only through intent or activity start for result. Actually i want to add photo to contact stored in phone memory .

Comment: Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: i want to get those contact which is stored in phone memory only not those store in sim card memory